# can't find downloaded skype

Tags: skype

I've downloaded skype onto my lubuntu machine (dell mini 1210). But I can't see it anywhere to run it. On ubuntu on a different machine the icon is visible but on lubuntu I've searched around but can't find it. Any ideas?

Comment: By searching around do you mean searching from Dash?

Comment: The file is probably in the `~/Downloads` folder. But you need to install it too: `sudo dpkg -i <path-to-file>`

Comment: Abhimanyu, I've seen dash on ubuntu but not seen similar in lubuntu. for searchin I'm looking at the menus available in the start button. Which gives system tools, package installer, software updater etc.

Comment: Gunnar, I'll see if I can find the path to file

Comment: found it!! I reinstalled and it is now on internet tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Skype and have downloaded and installed it successfully. It's downloadable at this site,  just choose the correct version of ubuntu. http://www.skype.com/de/download-skype/skype-for-computer/ enjoy !!! ;-)
Problem Solved !!! By the way,  I use Skype 4.3 for linux,  successfully in Ubuntu 14.04.1